# Query Logic vs Program Logic

Tags: sql, programming-languages

When developing a query to pass to a class or some other field filled object, is it better to let the business logic be applied at the query level, class level, and/or the interface level of a program?  I would think that you want to pass as much "base" information to a class that handles calcuation vs doing calculated fields within a query (like calculating the standard deviation of some number of values).  On the other hand, if you are running a query over a network that has low bandwith, like a WAN, would that change where the calculations should be performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about bandwidth, then it's advisable to keep the amount of data you pass back and forth as small as possible. I would then try to do as much of the logic as possible (e.g. calculations) in your query.

But if bandwidth is not an issue - separation of concerns should then compel you to have your data access layer (query) only concern itself with getting data from the datastore, and to place all your logic in the business logic layer (classes).